# How to make content in DIV align vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="content">ABC<div>UUU</div></div>
```

I just want to find some way to align vertically in middle for `div#content`. Actually I have some solutions. First one is using `line-height`, however it can not work if there's another `div` in the `div#content`. And `vertical-align:middle` I think just works for table? Is there any other usable solutions?

I try the vertical-align:middle and display:table-cell, the other issue comes,
 the width cannot works, i give that div a big width, that can fill out the screen(1438px), but now the width is also that number but just fill out the 1/3 width of screen.
The table-cell seems like make every cell in the screen, but i just want to give them specified length for table cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this for your requirement

```
#content {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `display:table-cell` declared on your element, vertical align will work.

```css
#content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

Comment: That takes away the `div`s block properties. So for instance you can't define the width anymore.

Comment: @Abody97 that's true but wasn't part of the question and regarding your first comment - the bracket notation is a common way to declare a placeholder mostly in cases where it does not matter or is not clearly enough defined.

Answer (score 0):

See thorough explanation on vertical alignment for both normal and inline DIVs at http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Expounding upon other answers using `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle`... Table cells cannot have 100% width, but their containers can!

#### Using a CSS Table

Items with a table display accept dynamic widths:

```
#existingContainer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px; /* example */
}
```

Say, with sample HTML:

```
<div id="existingContainer">
    ...
    <div id="content">ABC<div>UUU</div></div>
    ...
</div>
```

#### Using a Clearing Div

Alternatively, putting your table-cell directly into a block element will ensure no inline elements sit beside it:

```
<div id="newContainer">    
    <div id="content">ABC<div>UUU</div></div>
</div>
```

With sample CSS:

```
#newContainer {
    display: block;
}
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100px; /* example */
}
```